# Ansible handlers - exclusive restart or reload

Tags: ansible, systemd

I have a number of Ansible roles that notify handlers to either restart or reload systemd services.  If a restart is notified, there's obviously no need to do a reload of the same service and trying to do both can lead to failure as the reload comes too quickly after the restart.  Is there a way to configure the handlers so that the reload task only triggers if a restart task hasn't run?

Below is an example of my current restart/reload handler.

```
- name: Restart foo service
  systemd:
    name: foo
    daemon_reload: yes
    state: restarted
  become: yes

- name: Reload foo service
  systemd:
    name: foo
    daemon_reload: yes
    state: reloaded
  become: yes
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can notify a handler from a handler, so you can implement what you want, for example in this way (or using logical operators):

```
- name: Restart foo service
  set_fact:
    foo_state: restarted
  changed_when: true
  notify: Reload foo service

- name: Reload foo service
  systemd:
    name: foo
    daemon_reload: yes
    state: "{{ foo_state | default('reloaded') }}"
  become: yes
```

<sup>Handler names are a matter of preference, I'm leaving them as they are.</sup>

Comment: Cool one @techraf

Comment: `changed_when: true` is critical. Without that option, the `Reload foo service` handler will never be triggered unless some other task triggered it.

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution is to register handler's status and use it in `when` statement, so your sample will look like:

```
- name: Restart foo service
  systemd:
    name: foo
    daemon_reload: yes
    state: foo_restarted
  become: yes
  register: restarted

- name: Reload foo service
  systemd:
    name: foo
    daemon_reload: yes
    state: reloaded
  become: yes
  when: foo_restarted is not defined
```